# Setting styles through setAttribute function of an element

Tags: javascript, html

Am I using setAttribute correctly? When I click reset after say clicking "blue" button, box has no color but it seems like it is still setting the height to 150px. What am i doing wrong here?

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
});



document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});


document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("box").setAttribute("style", "backgroundColor: orange; height:150px");
});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you are using `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`

Button `Reset1` is the correct way to write your function, but it is overriding all the styles (like the `width`, `padding`, `margin`...)

So I wrote another function on click of the button `Reset 2` that must do what you are looking for. But you must try it, without clicking on `Reset 1` since it will remove all the other styles

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height="250px";
});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";
});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").setAttribute("style","background-color:orange; height:150px");
});

document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height="150px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="orange";
});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset 1</button>
<button id="button5">Reset 2</button>
```

Comment: so i just added the styles in two separate lines for button 4, but is there a way to just have them all together and have it produce what i want it to?           
  document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height="150px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="orange";
});

Comment: you must use the function of `button5` if you want to change only the `height` and the `background color`, because `setAttribute('style', ...)` will remove all the style attributes set to this element and replace them with the new ones. So your best solution is to replace each style alone like we are doing in `button5`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `setAttribute` overrides all your other styles and always try to use their properties from the style object like you did in other click events.

### You are almost there

If you still trying to learn with setAttribute, the problem is that there is no `backgroundColor` in native css. You have only `background-color`. Change it and it works.

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height="250px";
});



document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";
});


document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("box").setAttribute("style","background-color:orange; height:250px");
  });
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Do not confuse with javascript properties and with native css properties. Javascript represents css properties with camelcase letters with in `style` object of `element`.

Comment: this makes sense, because even when i use background-color, although it changes the color, and height, the width does not take on what i initially set it to in html. Learned something new today! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `document.getElementById("box").style` like you did before.

```
document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="orange";
    document.getElementById("box").style.height="150px"
});
```

Comment: is there any way to combine these styles? or is this the only way?